# VSCode can not open source file "xx.h" with this file exists and in includePath

Tags: visual-studio-code, xgboost

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 vscode to run xgboost test, the test file shows error in editor (and many errors similar with this)

```
cannot open source file "xgboost/data.h"
```

This file locates in `xgboost(WORKSPACE)/include/xgboost/data.h`, and quick fix suggest to add `"${workspaceFolder}/include"`

And my `c_cpp_properties.json` has them in includePath:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/include/c++/9",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9",
                "/usr/include/c++/9/backward",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/dmlc-core/include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

How to get it work? Any idea is welcome.

Update: the error is in a test file, I found in a src file it works, which is really weird.
[image: My screen shot]

What's more weird: when VSCode is opened and loading, there is a short period of time that I could use ctrl+click to goto the header file. And after that the error squiggle appears and I could not goto the header file anymore.